# export csv file from mysql database in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, import, export

I have done import in laravel 5 but facing some problem while exporting file.
code is not proper and doesnot give any logic.
I have tried similiar to documentation

```
public function exportData(Test $test,Excel $excel){
  $test=$test->all();
    Excel::create('Test excel', function($test) {

    $test->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet) {

        $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');

    });

})->export('xls');
    }
```

how to export csv file from mysql?
I am using "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.0.0" package

Answer (score 2):

You can use [INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) in Laravel

```
public function exportData($file_name) {

          $file = public_path()."/downloads/".$file_name; //CSV file is store this path

          $query = sprintf("select * from tests INTO OUTFILE '%s' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'",$file);

         \DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);
    }
```

Comment: i am using maatwebsite/excel package

Comment: This solution does not require ANY external libraries. It can implemented in Laravel "as is."

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [`league/csv`](http://csv.thephpleague.com/) package. They have [an example of exporting a database query to CSV](http://csv.thephpleague.com/examples/#exporting-a-database-table-as-a-csv-document). In your case, it would look something like:

```
public function exportData() {
    // get the data
    $data = Test::all();

    // get a Writer object for writing to CSV
    $csv = League\Csv\Writer::createFromFileObject(new SplTempFileObject());

    // add the data to the writer
    $csv->insertAll($data);

    // output the file
    $csv->output('testdata.csv');
}
```

Comment: i am using maatwebsite/excel package

Comment: I see that you have edited your original post to include this information. That being said, is it absolutely necessary that you use that specific package? Both my answer and the answer by @jay-dhameliya will solve your problem rather easily.